# Visual Basic Array Push

Tags: vb.net

I am currently iterating through a loop and redimensionalising my array every time I need to add a value (as you can imagine this takes some time for a redim every loop) is there a way I can implement a push similar to ruby or java? This would need to save the processing time needed to redimensionalise the array every time I need to add a value to it.

Cheers
Martin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd be better off using a `List (Of Type)`.  Then you can just call the `Add` method.

For example:

```
Dim foo As New List(Of String)
foo.Add("Bar")
```

Comment: A improved example could ease the things a little bit for the people who are looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat the array, with a array containing only the new item, or multiple.

```
Array.Concat({Item}).ToArray
```